# How to load a portion of a Page Using Ajax in JQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am Working on Asp.net MVC application and I am using the following code in the Success method of the Ajax call in JS.

```
window.location.href = "Some Url Path" + Id(Say 123456);
```

The problem is that the entire page is being loaded after the ajax call. Please suggest me a solution so that the partial part of the page has to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a portion using jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

```
$('#divId').load("url");
```

> **Description**: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**Syntax** .load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )

**url**
Type: String
A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

**data**

Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

**complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)**

Type: Function()
A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

Comment: id is some query string value

Comment: If i am using .load function then the page is displayed as blank i.e., contents of the page are not loaded :(

Answer (score 0):

By using $('#divId').html(data) or
$('#divId').replaceWith(data) in the ajax success function we can replace a portion of page without reloading whole page. "data" is the partialview returned from controller.